# In application.yml, boolean field is-enabled always getting read as default value false

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, yaml, lombok

I am working on the toggle module where I have to define toggle status in `application.yml` file but the surprising part is boolean value defined in yaml file when fetched in `spring-boot` code is always showing the default value as false however value in yaml file is true.

But we I rename `is-enable` to `enable` things work fine, is there any naming conversion restrictions in `yaml` files?

---

`application.yml` file values

```yaml
name: test-YAML
environment: testing
is-enabled: true
```

Config File goes as below:-

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ConfigurationProperties
@Data
public class YAMLConfig {
    private String name;
    private String environment;
    private boolean isEnabled;
    private List<String> servers = new ArrayList<String>();
    private List<String> external = new ArrayList<String>();
    private Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    private Component component = new Component();
}
```

I am running my main application like this

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private YAMLConfig myConfig;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(MyApplication.class);
        app.run();
    }

    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("name:" + myConfig.getName());
        System.out.println("enabled:" + myConfig.isEnabled());
    }
```

Let me know if more details required. I using sample project from [project-from-git](https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/tree/master/spring-boot-modules/spring-boot-properties)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is beacause your properties will be bind using setters if you are using default constructor.

See [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.typesafe-configuration-properties.java-bean-binding)

So, when you have class like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ConfigurationProperties
@Data
public class YAMLConfig {

    private String name;
    private String environment;
    private boolean isEnabled;
...
}
```

As you know, Lombok will generate getters and setters for you, so it will look like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ConfigurationProperties
@Data
public class YAMLConfig {

    private String name;
    private String environment;
    private boolean isEnabled;
    private List<String> servers = new ArrayList<String>();
    private List<String> external = new ArrayList<String>();
    private Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

    ...



    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return isEnabled;
    }

    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        isEnabled = enabled;
    }
}
```

If you have property **is-enabled** in your yml file, since this is boolean value, spring will look for setter **setIsEnabled** in your class, and since that setter doesn't exist it won't bind value for you, so`isEnabled` property will be set to `false` by default.

if you add manually setter like this:

```
 public void setIsEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        isEnabled = enabled;
    }
```

Your property should be bind.

BTW, you shoud avoid using `@ConfigurationProperties` withot specifying prefix.

Answer (score 0):

I used @Setter and @Getter instead of @Data, it's worked for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).